# List available test cases in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, testing, automation, android-testing

I'm developing a test automation for both Android and iOS. I want to list all available test case like this;

```
com.android.Class1#testA
com.android.Class1#testB
com.android.Class2#testA
...
```

I have already found this for Android;

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r -e log true -e package 'com.android' com.android.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

But this code give me only the test cases that installed on connected device. Is there any way to list all available test cases?